# Error when adding github as a gem source

Tags: rubygems

When I use the following: gem sources -a http://gems.github.com 
I get the error:

Error fetching http : // gems.github.com:
    timed out (http : // gems.github.com/specs.4.8.gz)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Ok, just solved the problem using a proxy. My network probably sucks ¬¬

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From terminal

> gem source --add http://gems.github.com

Or if you are using Gemfile, add on the top on the file

> source 'http://gems.github.com/'

Answer (score 0):

Please use follow command:

/sbin/ifconfig em1 mtu 1476 up
em1: your network card name

to make it permanent add command to /etc/rc.local file